# Create and Initialise Custom UITabBarItem Class

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am building an application with four `UITabBarItems`. They all should look the same. Instead of customising them in their respective `UIViewController`, I am trying to build a custom `UITabBarItem` class and have the `UITabBarItems` inherit from it.

So far, this is the work I have done:

```
class CustomTabBarItem: UITabBarItem {


    func customiseTabBarItems() {
        // Customises the item on the tab bar

        // For normal state
       setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : Fonts.small!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: Colours.grey], for: .normal)

        // When highlighted
       setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : Fonts.small!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: Colours.white], for: .highlighted)
    }


}
```

and I have set each `UITabBarItem` as a subclass of my 'CustomTabBarItem' in the storyboard.

The issue, however, is that the functionality is not showing up for my `UITabBarItems`.

Any advice?

Comment: if you want just change color of items you can do it easily by storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am building an application with four UITabBarItems. They all should look the same

The way to make that happen is not to try some sort UITabBarItem subclass, but to use the [*appearance proxy*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance) for UITabBarItem. For example:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes( // ...
```

Do that in your app delegate `didFinishLaunching`. All tab bar items will be customized in accordance with your commands to the appearance proxy.